Finding all integer triples $(a, b, c)$ satisfying $\frac{a(b+c)^2 + b(c+a)^2 + c(a+b)^2}{3 + abc} = 4$
Find all integer triples $(a, b, c)$  such that   $\frac{a(b+c)^2 + b(c+a)^2 + c(a+b)^2}{3 + abc} = 4$
My Attempt
I started with the equation:
$$
\frac{a(b+c)^2 + b(c+a)^2 + c(a+b)^2}{3 + abc} = 4
$$
To simplify things, I decided to multiply both sides by (3 + abc):
$$
a(b+c)^2 + b(c+a)^2 + c(a+b)^2 = 4(3 + abc)
$$
Expanding the left side, I found:
$$
a(b^2 + 2bc + c^2) + b(c^2 + 2ca + a^2) + c(a^2 + 2ab + b^2) = 4(3 + abc)
$$
Next, I rewrote it as:
$$
ab^2 + 2abc + ac^2 + bc^2 + 2cab + ba^2 + ca^2 + 2abc + cb^2 = 12 + 4abc
$$
$$
ab^2 + ac^2 + ba^2 + bc^2 + ca^2 + cb^2 + 6abc = 12 + 4abc
$$
Combining like terms,
This simplifies to:
$$
ab^2 + ac^2 + ba^2 + bc^2 + ca^2 + cb^2 = 12-2abc
$$
After trying a few combinations, I realized it’s quite tricky to find integers that satisfy the equation.
I thought of factorising the expression but I don't see any clear factorization.
I'm feeling a bit stuck at this point. How can I proceed? Can anyone guide me?

Take $a=0,b=1$. Then $c=3$, or $c=-4$. This gives already two solutions, and permutations of it.

at "Combining like terms, I got" it should say $6abc$  on the left

ADDED  after
This simplifies to:
$$
ab^2 + ac^2 + ba^2 + bc^2 + ca^2 + cb^2 = 12-2abc
$$
the next step is
$$
ab^2 + ac^2 + ba^2 + bc^2 + ca^2 + cb^2 +2abc = 12
$$
where the left hand side is homogeneous and might factor.
===================================================================
after correcting the expanded equation, we have
$$  (b+c)(c+a)(a+b)  = 12  $$
Go Wild.
To check whether a ternary cubic form  can be factored, see the methods in Brookfield 2016
Actual factoring can be difficult, see How to show that if $x, y, z$ are rational numbers satisfying $(x + y + z)^3 = 9(x^2y + y^2z +z^2x)$, then $x = y = z$

That means  the permutations of $(1,3,0)$ and $(6,-5,6)$ are the only solutions.

@CircuitSage  well, no, see Dietrich's $a=0, b=1, c=-4$

Are there any more??

@CircuitSage  yes; including permutations 36
